# How to use apparmor inside lxc container?

Tags: lxc, apparmor

I have lxc container 'foo' created with ubuntu template in: 
/var/lib/lxc/foo/.

I have file a.out in /var/lib/lxc/foo/rootfs/home/ubuntu/test/ (or /home/ubuntu/test/ as visible from inside container).

I would like to use apparmor to prevent a.out from writing to 'test' folder. Is it possible and if yes, how should I configure apparmor/lxc?